# Can't resolve 'tsparticles'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to use tsparticles with React javascript, it is in my package-json, however it still show:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'tsparticles' in 'D:\coding\MyBlog\frontend\src\componeomponents'nts'
```

when I try to

```
import { tsParticles } from "tsparticles";
```

[my package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azsHV.png)

Can somebody kindly tell me what's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

For React you should install the following package

```
npm install react-tsparticles
```

And import it like this

```
import Particles from "react-tsparticles";
```

Read more about it and see some examples here
https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles/blob/main/components/react/README.md

Comment: Thank you for your reply!                               
 But when I try this,it still show:                                                 
 Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-tsparticles' in 'D:\coding\MyBlog\frontend\src\components'